# how to convert \u seperated to persian words?

Tags: python, encoding, encode

I have scraped some persian websites with playwright and srapy selector.I got stock and ihave word \u06cc\u0642\u0647 and I want to convert it to persian

```
from scrapy import Selector
        .
        .
        .
        p = (page.inner_html('html').encode())
        x = Selector(text=p)
```

this is my code
what is its code in python

Comment: have you tried to decode your response like `response.read().decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06cc/index.htm
Isn't that a letter that might be used in a Persian text? Why would you want to convert it?